# Type of message in javascript window alert

Tags: javascript

I am trying to alert the following,

```
1. alert(1+1+1+1+1);

//output: 5

2. alert('1'+1+1+1+1);

//output: 11111

3. alert(1+1+1+1+'1');

//output: 41

4. alert(1+1+'1'+1+1);

//output: 2111
```

Does anyone can explain about the type of message in alert ?

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Are you asking about type coersion? Or how the alert function works?

Comment: 2 3 4 are output by string, 1 is output by number

Comment: I am asking about data type conversion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright so in javasciprt, number + number + number = number (Your case 1)

Whereas, a number after string concatenates with the String, and results in a string as output '1'+1 = '11' + 1 = '111' and so on. (Your case 2)

In the third case, the string just comes at the end of the number which get's casted to string and result will simply be number followed by string in string form.. 2+'432' = '2432'.

Last case is the mix of all the above 1+1 = 2 + '1' = '21'+1 = '211'+1 = '2111'.

Answer (score -1):

Javascript is a weakly typed language with operator overloading. That is why you are getting those 'strange' behaviours.

Wow, operator overloading. huh?

The `+` in javascript has multiple functions. One being: `adding up numbers` and another one is `concatenating strings together`. this is called operator overloading. compared to PHP, adding up numbers is `+` but concatenating strings is `.`

The big problem with operator overloading is. What if we have String + Number. Or Number + String ?

Different rules apply:

```
1+1+1+1+1
```

This is easy, adding up 5 numbers.

```
'1'+1+1+1+1
```

This is harder one. What he sees is a String, so he concatenates it with the next part (the 2nd `1`). Then he continues. String(11) + 1, gives String(111) and so on.

The 3rd example is fun. he starts adding up all the numbers, untill he reaches the last `+` sign. And it no has Number(4) + String(1). So he converts the Number to a string and Concatenates them together.

Same goes for the last example. If one of the two is a String, the `+` sign is interpreted as a Contatenation.

Answer (score -1):

I was reading w3school's [Automatic type conversion](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_type_conversion.asp) and I think this is relevant from your question.

It says:

> When JavaScript tries to operate on a "wrong" data type, it will try to convert the value to a "right" type.

It says that the result is not always what you expect:

```
5 + null    // returns 5         because null is converted to 0
"5" + null  // returns "5null"   because null is converted to "null"
"5" + 1     // returns "51"      because 1 is converted to "1"  
"5" - 1     // returns 4         because "5" is converted to 5
```

Comment: w3fools.... And the explanation is completly of. This has nothing to do with "wrong" data type but more the interpreter switching type for better performance and stuff

Comment: It's explaining things in layman's term duh, I know your advanced but please be more considerate to developers who are still learning. If your talking too much jargons to look smart. You're not helping at all!